# D3 sankey diagram - enforce node position

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

Using the D3 Sankey plugin, I'm updating a Sankey diagram with new values (on changing the data, passing new values for the nodes and links -- keeping all of them consistent).  Is there functionality like d3.treemap's [sticky](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout#sticky) to maintain node and link orders on the page?  If not, is there an approach to building this?

```
var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(15)
    .nodePadding(10)
    .size([width, height]);
    .sticky(true)
```

I'm following the pattern here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. If you want to dive into the layout, here's where you want to look:

```
function computeNodeDepths(iterations) {
 var nodesByBreadth = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
    .entries(nodes)
    .map(function(d) { return d.values; });

initializeNodeDepth();
...
```

Notice that sortKeys points at d3.ascending. You'd want this to point to some kind of hard-wired value, which you'd need to compute either in the first iteration or in your data preparation. It will still get adjusted when the collision detection function is run, so you might see your nodes pushed out of position but this will give you the best chance to maintain some control.

Comment: Thanks -- any idea about the structure of the function that sortKeys takes?  I would guess function(a,b) {return myOrder.indexOf(a) - myOrder.indexOf(b)}

Comment: That's part of d3.nest(), it takes a sorting function like you would send to Array.sort(), which would be something like the function you describe, but I don't think that particular one would work. I'd recommend looking into Array.sort().