# Vertical sort of nodes in D3 Sankey diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to achieve a basic sankey diagram building on top of this example: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c9b90689c1438f57d649

By default they get sorted by value. I want to customize the vertical order of the nodes.  Here is an example:

[image]

In this case I'd like to always keep "A" on top.

Any thoughts on how to do that?

Similar question: [D3 sankey diagram - enforce node position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553793/d3-sankey-diagram-enforce-node-position)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify this function:

```
function center(node) {
  return node.y + node.dy / 2;
}
```

like this:

```
function center(node) {
   return 0;
}
```

and after modify ascendingDepth's function like this:

```
function ascendingDepth(a, b) {
  return b.y - a.y;
}
```

I found this in another question
[How to force y position of one branch in d3 sankey plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121764/how-to-force-y-position-of-one-branch-in-d3-sankey-plugin)